# Symmetries on sets of strings

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, symmetry

My question is a reference request about 
symmetries on sets of strings. I'm not a mathematician, so the
terminology I use below is probably very non-standard. My apologies.

**Terminology.**
Let $[n] = \{0, 1, ..., n-1\}$. A *permutation* of a string
$\sigma = (s_0, ..., s_{n-1})$ over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is a
permutation of $[n]$. We write $p\; \sigma$ for the string obtained
from $\sigma$ using $p$, i.e. $p\; \sigma = (s_{p\; 0}, ..., s_{p\;
(n-1)})$ Let's call such a permutation $p$ with $p\ \sigma = \sigma$
a *symmetry*. We call a permutation that only exchanges $i$ and
$j$, leaving everything else fixed, a *flip* and write flips as
$(i, j)$. For example

$$
   (2,4)\; hello = heoll
$$

Clearly, we can reconstruct any permutation on strings as the
composition of some flips. Let's call a flip a *flip-symmetry* if
it is a symmetry and non-trivial, ie. not $(i, i)$. We call a set $B$
of flip-symmetries of a fixed string $s$ a *basis* if any
(flip-)symmetry of $s$ can be build up from $B$. We can use the basis
$B$ to specify a 
group (maybe we should call it the automorphism group of
$\sigma$?) $G$ by it's presentation.
Clearly, strings, their bases and the induced group are in one-to-one
correspondence, up to injective renaming of the alphabet $\Sigma$.

**Problem.**
What I want to do is lift this treatment from strings to sets of equal-length 
strings. Let me give an example. Consider the set $S$,
consisting of the following strings:

- $ababbc$ with basis $(0,2), (1, 3), (3, 4)$.
- $abcbba$ with basis $(0,5), (1, 3), (3, 4)$.
- $cbabba$ with basis  $(2,5), (1, 3), (3, 4)$.

The obvious definition of symmetry for such a set is to say a
permutation $p : [6] \rightarrow [6]$ is a *permutation* of $S$
provided $s \in S$ implies $p\; s \in S$. We can extend the concept of
flip, basis etc to sets of strings. If we make this choice, the only
non-trivial flips of $S$ are

$$
   (0, 2) \quad
   (0, 5) \quad
   (2, 5)
$$

But now we have lost a lot of information: we can no longer recover
$S$ from such flips. That's because these flips ignore that the
symmetries of the members of $S$ are systematically related: From the
basis $(0,2), (1, 3), (3, 4)$ of $ababbc$ and the flip $ (0, 5)$ of
$S$, I can obtain the basis $(0,5), (1, 3), (3, 4)$ of $abcbba$ and so
forth. This can be written as a commutative diagram, for example like so:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
    ababbc & \stackrel{25}{\longrightarrow} & abcbba \\
    \downarrow _{05}  & & \downarrow _{02} \\
    cbabba & \stackrel{25}{\longrightarrow} & cbabba \\
\end{array}
$$

Sorry for the poor type-setting.

It seems to be the case that the non-trivial flips $(0, 2), (0, 5),
(2, 5)$ of $S$ somehow permute the bases of the underlying strings: we
have permutations of $S$ working on permutations of the members of
$S$. Let's call this phenomenon *higher-order permutations on 
strings*. They crop up in my work all the time.

**Question.** I wonder what the right framework is to think about
higher-order permutations on strings.  I'm sure they have been
thoroughly investigated already. What terms should I google for? Googling
"strings" or "symmetries" always leads to physics. I'm
  particularly interested in the kinds of groups and geometric objects
such higher-order symmetries induce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idea has indeed been studied extensively. You are basically talking about what is usually called the *group action* of a group $G$ on a set $S$, and that's probably the missing google term you want.

What you are calling a "flip" is usually called a transposition; and you have $G$ as the group generated by (in your terms, 'can be built up from') all transpositions $(i,j)$ for $i,j \in [n]$ (the "trivial" transpositions of the form $(i,i)$ are identical and are typically denoted as the identity element $e$).

What you are calling a "basis of $s$" for $s \in S$ is any set of transpositions which generate what is called the *stabilizer* of $s$ in $G$ defined as $G_s = \{g \in G : g(s) = s\}$. Note that more than one of your 'basis' sets can generate the same of $G_s$; e.g. $(0,2)(1,3)(3,4)$ is the same as $(0,2)(1,3)(1,4)$; so usually we are more interested in the properties of $G_s$ than which set of transpositions generated it.